# Q) c# Multi serialport receive solution?

Tags: c#, multithreading, serial-port

```
private void Serial_Event_1(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    bytes1 = 0;

    if (received_Sequence == 0)
    {
        SerialPort sData = sender as SerialPort;
        var th1 = new Thread(Serial_Event_Thread1);

        try
        {                    
            bytes1 = sData.BytesToRead;                
        }
        catch { }

        byte[] read_data_ = new byte[bytes1];
        linef_1 = new byte[bytes1];

        try
        {
            //  sData.Read(read_data_, 0, bytes1);
            sData.Read(linef_1, 0, bytes2);
            // linef_1 = read_data_;
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("1 handle error");
        }
        Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            th1.Start();
        });

        if (port_numbering > 1)
        {
            received_Sequence ++;
        }
    }

    if (port_numbering == 1)
        received_Sequence = 0;
}

private void Serial_Event_2(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    //Same as receivedevent 1
}

private void Serial_Event_Thread1()
{
    // The incoming data packets are analyzed and written to the richtextbox.
    //Even when using two or more serial communication without `enter code here`analyzing packets, only one port can communicate smoothly.
    //The `enter code here`other ports are not well received or do not work.  
}
```

enter code here

The length of the data received is 18 bytes.
I've done it a lot with one Serialport communication.
Please give me a hint if you have implemented two or more Serial communications.

It uses a total of four " ReceivedEvent " and handles data with separate threads.
If you use two or more ports, the data is normally sent from one port to another, and the data is not broken or data is not received.

We try to connect a total of four ports using the " multi-serialport " approach.
You want to receive data sequentially from each number to a sample of 20 ms.
Each " serialdatareceivevent " occurs, and data is displayed once a second.
I'm not sure how to correct it, but please help me.
Thank you for reading it here. 
I'll be looking forward to your help.

Comment: Please, format your code and review if this is a minimal example.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As you said, the code has been simplified as much as possible. Simply put, one Serialport communication works, while two or more Serialport communications do not work. Please help me..

Comment: Why not use the `DataReceived` event built into the SerialPort class?  You can have one for each SeriaPort object. The response is already on it's own thread.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/fi-fi/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: If more than one "DataReceivedEvent" is used, only one "DataReceivedEvent" is activated and no other events are activated.So I tried to use a thread for each "DataReceivedEvent", but it did not work.

Comment: You should make a `SerialPort` class for each COM port you want to send/recieve data on.  Each `SerialPort` should subscribe to it's own `DataReceived` event.  I have several application where I'm reading/writing serial data asynchronously, the `SerialPort` class handles all of that on its own thread.

Comment: The above code is the code I changed because I did not receive the data receive correctly if I only used ReceiveEvent.
I do not know why.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Serial_btn_1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Test_Timer.Interval = 15;
    Test_Timer.Tick += new System.EventHandler(TimerEventProcessor);
    Test_Timer.Start();
}

private void TimerEventProcessor(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        bytes1 = serialPort1.BytesToRead;
        bytes1 = serialPort2.BytesToRead;
        bytes1 = serialPort3.BytesToRead;
        bytes1 = serialPort4.BytesToRead;

        linef_1 = new byte[bytes1];
        linef_2 = new byte[bytes2];
        linef_3 = new byte[bytes3];
        linef_4 = new byte[bytes4];
    }
    catch { }

    try
    {
        serialPort1.Read(linef_1, 0, bytes1);
        serialPort2.Read(linef_2, 0, bytes2);
        serialPort3.Read(linef_3, 0, bytes3);
        serialPort4.Read(linef_4, 0, bytes4);
    }
    catch
    {
        //  MessageBox.Show("Read_data no");
    }

    Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        richTextBox1.AppendText(ByteToHex(linef_1));
        richTextBox2.AppendText(ByteToHex(linef_2));
        richTextBox3.AppendText(ByteToHex(linef_3));
        richTextBox4.AppendText(ByteToHex(linef_4));
    });
}
```

Timer speed 15ms.
Changed to the above source.
Can I get a problem when I receive data using a timer?